# Register More Than One Concrete for a Type : Seeing the Names Later

Tags: unity-container

Is there a way to see the "names" of the Unity registrations?

```
// Create container and register types using a name for each one
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, DataService>("DataIsFun");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, LoggingService>("LoggingIsFun");

// Retrieve a list of non-default types registered for IMyService
// List will only contain the types DataService and LoggingService
IEnumerable<IMyService> serviceList = myContainer.ResolveAll<IMyService>();
```

(the pseudo code above is from msdn)

Is there anyway to see the names ("DataIsFun", "LoggingIsFun") ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snipplets to find the names.

"ContainerRegistration" is the thing that has the info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660863%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

```
IEnumerable<IMyService> myIServices = container.ResolveAll<IMyService>();


IEnumerable<ContainerRegistration> registrations = container.Registrations.Where(reg => reg.RegisteredType == typeof(IMyService));



ContainerRegistration foundContainerRegistration = container.Registrations.Where(reg => reg.RegisteredType == typeof(IMyService) && reg.MappedToType == typeof(DataService>).FirstOrDefault();

if(null!=foundContainerRegistration)
{
    string x = foundContainerRegistration.Name;
}
```